# Почему Eclipse Kepler не распознаёт стандартный метод вывода?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse

Создаю простейший Spring-проект. Для просмотра результатов работы программы хочу использовать стандартную функцию вывода, но IDE ругается. В чём дело? Java [image: введите сюда описание изображения]8

Comment: Spring тут ни причем и Эклипс - тоже. Вы пишите код вне метода. Так нельзя. Можно только инициализировать поля класса, как это происходит в первых двух строках.

Comment: А вы наведите мышку на красную волнистую линию и почитайте что там будет написано :)

Comment: Спасибо, Nofate. Глупо даже как-то вышло :)